# SQL Case on left join with Nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, case, sql-null

I'm trying to to create a comparison query by left joining new data to original data and comparing the output. The query I have is quite simple but can't seem to get it to do what I want. I understand that I can't compare NULL values like other values, but I was hoping that by doing the ISNULL would give me the result I need:

```
SELECT  O.Ded1,         
        ISNULL(N.Ded2, 0) AS Ded2,      
        CASE
          WHEN O.Ded1 =  N.Ded2 THEN 'Correct' 
          ELSE 'Incorrect'
        END AS 'DED CHECK'

FROM #Tmp_ORIG_DATA O

LEFT JOIN #Tmp_NEW_DATA N ON O.ID = N.ID
```

I was wondering if I need to insert these values into a temp table to make them physical values?

Thanks in advance

Sorry I should have added the results from this query:

[image: > Ded1 Ded2 DED CHECK 0 0 Incorrect 0 0 Incorrect 0 0 Incorrect > 0 0 Incorrect 0 0 Incorrect 0 0 Incorrect 0 0 Incorrect 0 0 Incorrect]

Really I want the check to say Correct.

Thanks

Comment: How is `#Tmp_ORIG_DATA` defined?

Comment: `NULL` does not equal any other value including `NULL`. `NULL = NULL` returns UNKNOWN, which is (importantly) *not* TRUE. If you need to do a comparison where both values are `NULL`, then use` IS NULL` and an `AND`: `COL1 IS NULL AND COL2 IS NULL`.

Comment: Thanks all, I have just added the image of the results that I currently get.

Comment: Larnu - There is no Null values in the original data. So it is comparing 0 with Null, but I thought that by adding in the ISNULL(....,0) would get around that?

Comment: Expected result is fine,  but we need the sample table data as well - and most of us want it as formatted text, not images. [mcve]

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns null values for unmatched rows.

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly check for nullity. An additional check is needed to distinguish non-matching rows from matching rows where `Ded2` is `null`.

```
SELECT  
    O.Ded1,         
    N.Ded2,      
    CASE
        WHEN O.Ded1 =  N.Ded2
            OR (N.ID IS NOT NULL AND o.Ded1 IS NULL AND N.Ded2 IS NULL) 
        THEN 'Correct' 
        ELSE 'Incorrect'
    END AS 'DED CHECK'
FROM #Tmp_ORIG_DATA O
LEFT JOIN #Tmp_NEW_DATA N ON O.ID = N.ID
```